# Simple exercise about Limsup/Liminf of sets

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

I tried the following exercise regarding the limsup/liminf of sets. In the following let $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of events. Calculate the set-theoretic $\limsup_{n \to \infty}$ and $\liminf_{n \to \infty}$ of the following sequences of sets

> 1. Let $A_n = \{1\}$ if $n$ is even and $A_n = \{0\}$ if $n$ is odd.
> 2. $$ A_n = 
>          \begin{cases} 
>    (0,3+1/n) \quad & \text{if } n \text{ is odd} \\
>    (-1-1/n, 2] \quad & \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\
>          \end{cases} $$
> 3. $A_n = [\sin(n) - 1, \sin(n) + 1]$

Here is what I have tried.

1. $\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n = \{0,1\}$, since for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ one has $\cup_{k > n} A_n = \{0,1\}$, moreover we have $\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n = \emptyset$, since $A_{n} \cap A_{n+1} = \emptyset$.
2. $\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n = (-1,3]$ since $A_n \cup A_{n+1} = (-1-1/n, 3+1/n] =(0,3+1/n) \cup (-1-1/n,2]$, moreover $\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n = (0,2]$, since this intervalls is the only one that remains under intersection up to finitely many $n$.
3. Here I am not 100% sure. One can prove the following fact $\{\sin(n) : n \in \mathbb N\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. Hence for every $y \in [-1,1]$ one can find a sequence of rational points $(n_k)_{k \in \mathbf N}$ s.t.
   $$
   \sin(n_k) = y
   $$
   hence one can find a sequence $(n_k)$ and $(n^{\prime}_{k})$ such that $y \in \{-1,1\}$ is approximated, hence
   $$
   \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n = [-2,2]
   $$
   since all the the limit of both sequences is contained in $\cup_{k>n} a_k$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
   For the second part I believe $\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n = [-1,1]$, since for all other points one can find a natural number such that the intervall in not contain in $\textbf{all}$ next intervalls.

Sorry for the messy writeup, is this correctly solved, especially last part?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All correct except, I think that in$ 2$. $limsupA_{n}=[-1,3]$ i.e.$ -1$ belongs to the set!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do the second case:
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_{n} = \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_{k} & = \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n}(A_{2k}\cup A_{2k-1})\\\\
& = \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n}\left[\left(-1 - \frac{1}{2k},2\right]\cup\left(0, 3 + \frac{1}{2k-1}\right)\right]\\\\
& = \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n}\left(-1 - \frac{1}{2k}, 3 + \frac{1}{2k-1}\right)\\\\
& = \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\left(-1 - \frac{1}{2n},3 + \frac{1}{2n - 1}\right)\\\\
& = [-1,3]
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yes I forgot to include -1 aswell, thanks for detailed calculation and long answer.

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent you are welcome ! I am glad I could help.